# How to edit element width using react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'd like to edit my progress bar width by using react props.
In my code I have a certain value in the component state (state.progress).
How can I use it to properly stretch the progress bar,

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className = "bar" >
      <div className = "progress" >

      </div> 
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Hello name = "World" / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.progress {
  width: 5%;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Thanks folks!

Comment: Something like `style={{width: this.state.progress }}`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use inline style prop.

Example

```
  render() {
    return <div className="bar" >
      <div className="progress" style={{width: this.state.progress}} >
        // ...
      </div> 
    </div>;
  }
```

Comment: yeah, i thought about it but it looks awfully ugly and seems like coding in the 90'. Isn't there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `style={{width: this.state.progress + '%'}}` to the div with `progress` class

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are going to update progress with a call like this:

```
this.setState({ progress: 50})
```

Setting the state will trigger a re-render, which can control the width of your progress bar like this:

```
  <div className = "progress" style={{width: this.state.progress+"%"}}>
```

Comment: It sounds like that's the common way to do it. I was hoping react had some cleaner way to do that instead than using some 90' technique <,<   thanks anyway

Comment: it took 15 years to separate js / html and Css, and I'm bamboozled by the fact that now these 3 things are sticked together again, even if I understand that "it's all related to a single component"

Comment: Yeah, the world is circular. Keeping everything in separate files just means you spend time flicking between files (although that is still a necessity). At least things are all in one place now. The dream of separating concerns just wasn't that simple, so it's come back together. The programming world is borked :)

Comment: concern separation just moved from the language to the component.
React still separate concern, but it does it horizontally instead than vertically. 
https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-301fe369321c4502756e965d4ae91620

Comment: The more sugar you add to the framework, the less control you have over stuff like when does "width=10%" transform to "style=width:50%" and the more convoluted the rendering pipeline becomes. That kind of stuff hurts when you're doing something more complex than the helloworld tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the percentage value of the progress bar as the percentage width of the element with CSS through `style` attribute:

```
 <span className="fill" style={{width: this.state.value + '%'}}>
```